# Blur background overlay image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to blur the curved shape overlayed over slider that itself is a image which is a transparent png format, i want to make effect via css3 or jquery or any other.Help me out  [image  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUKk4.jpg)

this is my code

```
<div class="slider_overlay_menu">
    <div class="overlay_menu">
        <div class="banner_questions">
            <select style="width: 60%;">
                <option value="Career">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ?</option>
                <option value="Subject">Curabitur at erat ornare elit tristique porttitor eget at tellus ?</option>
                <option value="Stream">Fusce laoreet, tortor quis mattis congue, enim lacus vulputate tellus ?</option>
                <option value="Category">Ut imperdiet egestas purus non ultricies. Sed id aliquet magna ?</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Know How !">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.slider_overlay_menu
{
    float: right;
    position:relative;
}


.slider_overlay_menu:before
{
    -webkit-fliter:blur(5px);
}
.banner_questions
{
    float:right;
    width:825px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.overlay_menu input[type="submit"]
{
    margin-left:30px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.overlay_menu
{
    position: absolute;
    background: url('../images/banner_bg.png')no-repeat;
    height: 155px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1007px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99998;
    bottom: 10px;
    padding:2%;
}
```

Actually, my slider is responsive, its width is 100%, and the overlay green shape is also position absolute which means when we increase the page size of the browser its changes it position.

Bottom line: I want to blur the content behind the green shape.

Comment: Am not sure I understand your question, you want to blur the section with those 5 circle icons when the dropdown menu is active?

Comment: PFA i have marked the section that iz green shape.the slider image should me blurred in the green shape. and sry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

Just add `-webkit-filter` property for `.overlay_menu` like this:

```
.overlay_menu
{
    position: absolute;
    background: url('../images/banner_bg.png')no-repeat;
    height: 155px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1007px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99998;
    bottom: 10px;
    padding:2%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: Actually, my slider is responsive, its width is 100%, and the overlay green shape is also position absolute which means when we increase the page size of the browser its changes it position. Bottom line: I want to blur the content behind the green shape.